# How to create chart in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Right now I am working on Rails 3 version. I want to create chart in my application. I am using the lazy_high_charts gem, Please help me anyother possible way is there .How to do this?

Answer (score 7):

use

```
gem "chartkick"
```

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick

it good and better.

Answer (score 0):

you can use gruff, it is good an simple.
here is a tutorial:
http://enigmater.blogspot.fr/2012/06/how-to-rmagick-on-macos-generate-graphs.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 gem gruff
```

https://github.com/topfunky/gruff

and also check

http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts?view=asciicast